# Python's behaviour when initializing a class

Tags: python-3.x, class, static

I cannot get how the Python's class initialization works if, in one case, I use constants like ints and , in another case, some expressions like dict comprehension.

Both cases involving the usage of previously declared class (static) variables.

See a code snippet describing the problem:

```py
class Working(object):
  A = 5
  B = A
  # everything is initialized just as expected

class NotWorking(object):
    A = {
      'key': 'value',
    }

    print(f'Print A: {A}')  # {'key': 'value'}

    B = {
        k: A[k] for k in A.keys()
    }
    # Throws "NameError: name 'A' is not defined."
```

Why do two classes behave differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to clone B from A, there are other ways to do it. For multiple keys in A, the declaration for B doesn't really make sense.

```
class NowWorking
    A = { 'key': 'value',}
    B = {k:v for k,v in A.items()}
```

Instance variables should be declared in `__init__` method. Here are some resources for you to look at.

[Classes and Objects - LearnPython](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Classes_and_Objects)

[Hackerearth Notes](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/object-oriented-programming/classes-and-objects-i/tutorial/)

Comment: Thank you, Dileep. That actually works.
I do actually know how to clone dict (could use deepcopy as well), but I still don't get, why isn't my variant working...